# How do I create an Azure DevOps Repos for my Azure SQL DB?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have generated a dacpac file from SSMS, I created an SQL Server project in Visual Studio and I have no idea how to put all those scripts into Azure Devops Repos. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check-in those scripts to azure git as the developer does their code.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: store those scripts to one folder, initialize a git repo inside that and push it to the azure git repository

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry.